# NSData & NSURL - url with space having problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdata, nsurl

I have following code in my application.

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathOfThumbNail]];
```

pathOfThumbNail has following path

---

http://70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF 58B.jpg

---

When I open above path in safari browser - path is changed automatically & image is successfully displayed.

http://70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF%2058B.jpg

---

But in iPhone, due to space in path, image isn't loaded in nsdata.

Comment: Brilliant question, stumbled upon this by accident when having a similar issue.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:

Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

```
-(NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

A representation of the receiver using encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string. Returns nil if encoding cannot encode a particular character

Added per request by @rule

```
NSString* urlText = @"70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF 58B.jpg";
NSString* urlTextEscaped = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlTextEscaped];
NSLog(@"urlText:        '%@'", urlText);
NSLog(@"urlTextEscaped: '%@'", urlTextEscaped);
NSLog(@"url:            '%@'", url);
```

NSLog output:

```
urlText:        '70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF 58B.jpg'  
urlTextEscaped: '70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF%2058B.jpg'  
url:            '70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF%2058B.jpg'
```

Comment: Great ! Exactly as I wanted. Actually I knew it but forgotten due to project load. Hats of for your kind help to me.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good, but you should give an example like:

NSString* urlText = @"http://70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF 58B.jpg";
urlText = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlText];

Comment: Note: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding doesn’t encode reserved characters like ampersand (&) and slash (/)

Answer (score 16):

A swift 3.0 approach (stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding and stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters seems now deprecated):

```
let urlString ="your/url/".addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Answer (score 5):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` has been deprecated in iOS 9.0, it is recommended you use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` instead.

Here's the Objective-C code for > iOS 9.0

```
NSString* urlText = @"70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/TipThumb/GOLF 58B.jpg";
NSString* urlTextEscaped = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlTextEscaped];

NSLog(@"urlText:        '%@'", urlText);
NSLog(@"urlTextEscaped: '%@'", urlTextEscaped);
NSLog(@"url:            '%@'", url);
```