# Do I need a helper application to launch my main application at login?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am creating this macOS application that offers the user the option to launch at login.

I have googled around and found a recipe that everyone is following for centuries, where a helper app is created and then this helper launches at login and from there, launches your main app.

Is that really necessary? Can't the main app launch directly at login?

I don't see any documentation from Apple saying that this scheme is mandatory.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:

- There is always the option to add the application manually to the Login Items in System Preferences > Users & Groups (no helper app).
- Otherwise if the main app is sandboxed the helper app is mandatory.
- Otherwise you could add a custom launchd agent which launches the application.

Comment: ah, this is what was not clear on my mind. My problem here is that the app is sandboxed, so, I need a helper. Thank. BTW, there is [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786493/macos-impossible-to-launch-an-app-wit-localized-name-and-space), related to launching an app from the helper, that you may be interested...